# How to get the product of two integers without using *

Tags: javascript, math, integer

I am trying to figure out ways to get the products of two integers without using * in my solution. The closest I got was is

```
/*Example: 2,5 output ====> 10 */
/*Example: 10,5 output ====> 50 */

const productOfTwoInt = (int,int2) => {
  var data1 = 0;
  var data2 = 0;

  var result;
  var result2;  

  for(var x = 0; x <= int; x++) {
      result = x += data1
      console.log(result)
  }

  for(var j = 0; j <= int2; j++) {
      result2 = j += data2
  }

  return result + result2    
}

console.log(productOfTwoInt(3,5))
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < int; i++) result += int2;`

Answer (score 7):

You could take some bit shifting, known as [ancient egyptian multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) or [russian multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RussianMultiplication.html).

> ```
>   a     b     p   comment
> ----  ----  ----  ----------------------------------
>   6     8     0   skip, because a is even
>   3    16    16   add 16 to p, because a is odd
>   1    32    48   add 32 to p, because a is odd
>   0    64    48   stop iteration, because a is zero
> ```

```js
function product(a, b) {
    var p = 0;
    while (a) {
        p += (a & 1) && b;
        a >>= 1;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return p;
}

console.log(product(6, 8)); // 48
```

Comment: nice one ;) how about negative numbers?

Comment: @Jonasw, you coud store the sign and apply it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with inverse like this:

```
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a / (1 / b)
}

multiply(2, 5)  // 10
multiply(10, 5)  // 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks quite good already. That can be a bit simplified to:

```js
function multiply(a,b){
  //just one minus, lets swap
  if(a<0 && b>0) [a,b] = [b,a];
  //two minuses: let them be positive
  if(a<0 && b<0) ( a = Math.abs(a), b = Math.abs(b) );
  var result = 0;
  while(a--){
    result += b;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  multiply(1,2),
  multiply(3,4),
  multiply(6,7),
  multiply(-1,-2),
  multiply(1,-2)
);
```

Comment: If `a` is negative you'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
const productOfTwoInt = (x, y) => {
    let z = Math.log(x) + Math.log(y);
    return Math.round(Math.exp(z));
}

console.log(productOfTwoInt(3,5))
```

Comment: Smart, but will only work for positive integers. Try `productOfTwoInt(-2, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Nina Scholz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46410329/6904230), the "Russian Multiplication":

```js
const productOfTwoInt = (a, b) => {

    var a0 = a;
    var result = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (a0 % 2 !== 0)
            result += b;
            
        if (a0 == 1 || a0 == -1) break;
        
        a0 = Math.floor(a0 / 2);
        b *= 2;
    }
  return a > 0 ? result : -result;
}

console.log(
    productOfTwoInt(4, 5),
    productOfTwoInt(4, -5),
    productOfTwoInt(-40, 5),
    productOfTwoInt(-4, -50)
);
```

Traditional solution:

```js
 const productOfTwoInt = (int, int2) => {
        
        let result = 0;
        let isPositive = int > 0;
        let i = 0;
    
    
        while (i != int) {
            result += int2;
            if (isPositive)
                i++;
            else
                i--;
        }
    
 return isPositive ? result : -result;
    
    }
    
    console.log(
      productOfTwoInt(4, 5),
      productOfTwoInt(4, -5),
      productOfTwoInt(-4, 5),
      productOfTwoInt(-4, -5)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use do it in this way

**Option 1**

```
function mul(m,n){
   // make it more efficient
    if(m<n)
     {
      var temp =m;
      m=n;
      n=temp;
     }   
 var v=0;
 if(n==1) 
      return m;
 v = mul(m,n>>1);
 v = v+v;
 if(n&1) 
      v+= m;
 return v;
}

console.log(mul(-2,5));
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Suvethan/rqysspso/1/)